# IIS Authentication Tab doesn't open on double click

Tags: iis, iis-8, iis-10

This is the operation i'm doing:

- Open IIS Console
- Select the Website
- Double click at Authentication Icon

[image: Authentication double click]

When I click this error occurs, only at that site (I have many sites configured, and this is the only one that I'm getting this error)

[image: Error Authentication]

And then the panel show me that, and don't let me change the Authentication type. I need to Allow Anonimous Authentication, but I can't because of this error.

[image: Authentication Tab]

When I click Enable or Edit, the same pop-up error came up.

And also, when I try to access the website in any browser, I get this message:
[image: Browser Error]

My web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\IdentityServer.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="true" startupTimeLimit="3600" requestTimeout="23:00:00" hostingModel="InProcess">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        <environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44339" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </aspNetCore>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <add verb="PUT" allowed="true" />
          <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="4096" />
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Xss-Protection" />
        <!--<add name="X-Xss-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
                <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="script-src 'self' h.online-metrix.net 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self' h.online-metrix.net; frame-src 'self'  h.online-metrix.net; default-src 'self'  h.online-metrix.net;" />-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3ACFC0B0-4FDD-4549-AFBD-C3FF653F5886-->
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Well known OOB issue, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/oob-500.html

Comment: @LexLi I was missing the ASP.NET Core module. Thank you for the link!